# How to dynamically add dropdown items to bootstrap-editable?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I have initialised and rendered the bootstrap-editable in select/select2 mode.

Now i want to modify the drop down item list through an event.

Currently i am reinitialising the editable DOM element and calling editable over the same DOM element again.But it has no effect.

Is the above possible? If so How to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" id="group" data-type="select" data-name="group" data-pk="1" data-value="5" data-source="groups.php" data-original-title="Select group">Admin</a>
```

in your groups.php ... return json encoded data.. from a php array